# Make install Command - Permission Denied

Tags: permissions, make

I'm trying to install `glew` and `freeglut` so I can program OpenGL. I have figured out how to fix my `make all` command but when I type `make install` I get this message:

```
Making install in src
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/connor/Documents/freeglut-2.8.1/src'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/connor/Documents/freeglut-2.8.1/src'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/lib'
 /bin/bash ../libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c   libglut.la '/usr/local  /lib'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libglut.so.3.9.0 /usr/local/lib/libglut.so.3.9.0
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file '/usr/local/lib/libglut.so.3.9.0': Permission denied
make[2]: *** [install-libLTLIBRARIES] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/connor/Documents/freeglut-2.8.1/src'
make[1]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/connor/Documents/freeglut-2.8.1/src'
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

How can I grant the permission?

Comment: Did you use `sudo`? So `sudo make ...`.

Comment: Please selected my answer as the chosen answer if it was what you were looking for, to help future guests find the answer faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can install `glew` and `freeglut` without implementing difficult compilations. They are in Official Ubuntu Repository.

```
sudo apt-get install freeglut3 libglew1.10 glew-utils
```

Comment: I get a bunch of messages saying    undefined reference to `glutInit'and every glut, gl and glew thing I use

Comment: I'm using netbeans for OpenGL

Answer (score 0):

Did you use `sudo`? So do `sudo make ...`.

`sudo` stands for Super User DO. Be careful when using `sudo` because you can do a lot of damage, as you can run any command harmful or not.